# JavaScript Multiline String

Tags: javascript, string, multiline, heredoc

The question is:

What is the JavaScript method to store a multiline string into a variable like you can in PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by "grab"? From where?

Comment: check my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/19970452/209797

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If by 'multiline string' you mean a string containing linebreaks, those can be written by escaping them using `\n` (for newline):

```
var multilineString = 'Line 1\nLine 2';
alert(multilineString);
// Line 1
// Line 2
```

If you mean, how can a string be written across multiple lines *of code*, then you can continue the string by putting a `\` backslash at the end of the line:

```
var multilineString = 'Line \
1\nLine 2';
alert(multilineString);
// Line 1
// Line 2
```

Answer (score 15):

```
var es6string = `<div>
    This is a string.
</div>`;

console.log(es6string);
```

Comment: Note: This only works with ES6 and, at the time of this writing, is not well supported in IE11 or Safari.

Comment: This is becoming the correct answer.

Comment: Ugh why does JS need to reinvent the wheel. This should be a subprocess.

Answer (score 9):

Based on previous answers and different use cases, here is a small example:

https://gist.github.com/lavoiesl/5880516
Don't forget to use /*! to avoid the comment being removed in minification

```
function extractFuncCommentString(func) {
  var matches = func.toString().match(/function\s*\(\)\s*\{\s*\/\*\!?\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*\*\/\s*\}/);
  if (!matches) return false;

  return matches[1];
}

var myString = extractFuncCommentString(function(){/*!
  <p>
    foo bar
  </p>
*/});
```

Comment: I've never seen this before, I don't know how practical this would be, but this is helluva creative way to handle multiline strings! +1

Answer (score 5):

Only (?) way to have multiline strings in Javascript:

```
var multiline_string = 'line 1\
line 2\
line 3';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myString = [
  'One line',
  'Another line'
].join('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

**This works:**

```
var htmlString = "<div>This is a string.</div>";
```

**This fails:**

```
var htmlSTring = "<div>
  This is a string.
</div>";
```

**Sometimes this is desirable for readability.**

*Add backslashes to get it to work:*

```
var htmlSTring = "<div>\
  This is a string.\
</div>";
```

**or this way**

```
var htmlSTring  = 'This is\n' +
'a multiline\n' + 
'string';
```