# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an object in javascript that has an object inside of it and I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

This is my code

```
var motivateEN = {
    0 : {0: "{name}, keep studying this lesson for a better score.", 1: "Bad luck {name}, keep studying this lesson to improve.
"},
    50:{0: "Practice makes perfect {name}, try this lesson again.",1:"Not bad, but better luck next time {name}!",2:"Well done {name}, you’re on the right track!"},
    85:{0:"Congratulations {name}, lesson complete!",1:"Woohoo, lesson complete {name}!",2:"Awesome stuff {name}! Keep it up!",3:"Great skills! Well done {name}!
"},
    100:{0: "Perfect {name}! Keep up the good work!",1:"Congratulations {name}, you got a perfect score!"} 
};
```

Comment: The issue is in the strings literals, which aren't allowed to span multiple lines. You can use the `\n` and `\r` [escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) to include line breaks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391628/javascript-multiline-string

Answer (score 2):

If you take this code and format it, the error is more obvious:

```
var motivateEN = {
    0: {
        0: "{name}, keep studying this lesson for a better score.",
        1: "Bad luck {name}, keep studying this lesson to improve.
        "},
...
```

You can't use a newline in the middle of a string

Comment: Thanks I tried to do javascript:alert(motivateEN.0.0);  but returns an error?

Comment: @Jake To access numeric properties, you'll [have to use bracket notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026741/how-to-access-a-numeric-property) -- `motivateEN[0][0]`. Numbers aren't on their own valid identifiers, which is what dot notation expects.